# Is the sum of a dense map and a nowhere dense map dense?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be non-zero normed linear spaces, if $A:X\rightarrow Y\ $ has dense image and $B:X\rightarrow Y\ $ has nowhere dense image, does it necessarily imply $A+B\ $ has dense image? $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily meant to be linear or continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A:\mathbb{R}^3 \to\mathbb{R}^3 $, $A(x,y,z) =(x,y,z)$, $B:\mathbb{R}^3 \to\mathbb{R}^3$, $B(x,y,z) =(-x,-y,0) $ then $A$ has dense image $B$ has nowhere dense image but $A+B$ has not dense image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a counterexample with $X=Y$: Let $A$ be the identity and $B$ be the "indicator function" of the unit ball $D \subset X$; that is,

$$ B(x) = \begin{cases}
v & \Vert x \Vert <1 \\
0 & \Vert x \Vert \ge 1
\end{cases}$$

where $v \in X$ satisfies $\Vert v \Vert > 1$. These $A$ and $B$ satisfy the required conditions; but the image of 
$$ F(x) = (A+B)(x) = \begin{cases}
x+v & \Vert x \Vert <1 \\
x & \Vert x \Vert \ge 1
\end{cases}$$

is not dense at zero: if $\Vert x \Vert \ge 1$ then $$\Vert F(x) \Vert = \Vert x \Vert \ge 1,$$ and if $\Vert x \Vert < 1$ then $$\Vert x + v \Vert \ge | \Vert v \Vert - \Vert x \Vert | > \Vert v\Vert-1 > 0.$$